# this.source is not a function. Error with jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

jQuery-ui is throwing an error when attempting to use the autocomplete method

```
jquery-ui.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function
    at t.<computed>.<computed>._search (jquery-ui.min.js:8)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>._search (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>.search (jquery-ui.min.js:8)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>.search (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
    at t.<computed>.<computed>.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:8)
    at i (jquery-ui.min.js:6)
```

Here is my code

```
$.get('https:/{{pretend there is a proper url here}}/hygiene.php', {op: 'search', business: val}, (res) => {
    res = JSON.parse(res);
    var businesses = res.map(r => {return r.business})

    $('#search-form').autocomplete({
        sources: businesses,
        appendTo: '#search-form'
    })
})
```

op and business are simply paramters required from the API to work.
The API works and there's nothing wrong with the call.
The call returns a json string of businesses (hence the JSON.parse)
Calling map on the parsed array is to return only the names of the businesses as that is what I would like to display in the autocomplete.

search form is a text input

```
<input type='text' id='search-form'/>
```

Am pretty sure it is an issue with jQuery and not my code.
Using:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js cdn

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ should be source not sources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be source not sources

https://codepen.io/ernerock/pen/ByoqVo

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Rock",
      "Rap",
      "Trova",
      "Blues",
      "Country",
      "Folk",
      "Jass",
      "POP",
      "Electronic"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Comment: I owe you my life. Thank you